# Two floated divs - both full width on resize

Tags: css

I have two divs within a container

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="left"><img src="logo.jpg" width="160" /></div>
    <div id="right">
        <h2>Name</h2>
        <h3>Address</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the browser is resized I would like both divs to fill the width of the parent container with the contents of the left div being centered.

I can accomplish this with Media Queries using:

```
/* Base Style */
#left, #right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Large Devices */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #left, #right {
        float: left;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

This however has its problems as the content in the right div is variable so the break point will always be different depending on the content loaded.

Is it possible to make both divs 100% width automatically when they can no longer be inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:table-cell` to achieve what you want - this allows for vertical aligning too:

No styles for normal width then this media query:

```
/* Large Devices */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {display:table; width:100%;} 
    #left {text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;}
    #right {vertical-align:top; width:100%;}
    #left, #right {
        display:table-cell;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dS2Z5/3)

Comment: almost perfect. Just need to add a right margin to the left div to give a bit of space between the two divs. Solved by adding padding-right: 1.25rem;.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    #left, #right {
        width: 100%;       
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why `width: auto`? You can use percentages if the `#left` is 1/2 of the screen and the `#right` is 1/2 of the screen, such as `width: 50%`. Even more nifty stuff can be done with the CSS3 [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcalc) function. That said, CSS isn't very good with mathematics so perhaps Javascript?

On the top of my head:

```
/* get window width */
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

/* update window width on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
});

/* sizes */
var leftWidth = $('#left').width();
var rightWidth = $('#right').width();
var maxWidth = 600; /* half of 1200px, or whatever you want

/* magic, or if #left exceeds the max width, both #left and #right go block */
if(leftWidth > maxWidth) {
  $('#left, #right').css({'display':'block', 'width': + windowWidth + 'px'});
}
```

Note that the above is done with the help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: Was originally using percentages for widths but I wasn't happy with the amount of spacing between elements at large screen sizes even with tweaking the percentages at multiple break points.

Comment: Have you tried tweaking with calc? Width: calc(50% - 20px) for example.